# How can link network devices on the different docker containers?

Tags: docker, networking

I have one docker container that's created some network device. For example has been vpn device eg `/sys/class/net/my-device` and one have specified subnet:

```
(container1) $ route -n
default         172.18.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 my-device
...
```

Also I have another container in the same network but I need an access for `my-device` subnet, but I see:

```
(container2) $ route -n 
default         172.18.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
... (no 192.168.0.0)
```

How I can automatically share network device `my-device` with their subnet from container1 to container2 only using docker tools (without iptables on the host)?

I tried understand the problem at the two days ((

Comment: What code that you've written creates a network device?  Normally Docker fully manages the container network environment, and containers' limited capabilities mean you can't normally modify this.  As you've written it the question seems a little more like a network-setup problem than a programming problem, and a different site might be a more appropriate place to ask.

Comment: I use the wireguard image (client) with cap_add NET_ADMIN and SYS_ADMIN. It create VPN connection and new device with required subnet that I need to use in another container